# USB drive becomes unresponsive over time

Tags: usb, 20.04, hard-drive, persistence, exfat

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 persistent on a 64gb USB. I have another USB HDD I plug in, formatted as exFAT, which works for a while then after opening 1-2 files or going into a particular folder, the folders and files no longer appear when I open the drive, I just see an endless loading wheel, in this state I cannot browse the drive via terminal, it cannot be dismounted, if I physicall unplug, it still hangs around in the system and I must restart. The issue seems to be related to browsing it using file managers?

Things I have tried

- works fine on a proper 20.10 install
- works fine on mx linux persistant USB
- works ok If I only open files via terminal?
- tried thunar file manager and same issue
- tried exFAT fschk which had no issues
- tried turning off thumbnails

Any ideas here?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had these same symptoms trying to use an exFAT formatted USB drive plugged into a virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04 (through VMWare).  The fix for me was changing from USB 2.0 to USB 3.0 in the VMWare settings under USB Compatibility.

Even though my setup is different from the one you described, I had the exact same symptoms so hopefully my solution gives you a troubleshooting idea.
Good luck!